# java heap space problem in remote desktop

Tags: java, windows

I have remote logged into my machine and trying to start tomcat server. But, I get the following error.

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Apparently there are some memory restrictions when logged into remote desktop. Is there any way I can start the tomcat from RDP?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to increase the maximum heap size?

Comment: chances are this is related to how you launch tomcat, and nothing to do with remote desktop

Comment: Yoni, I have the same problem over Remote Desktop but while logged into the machine directly I have no trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remote desktop could be causing the problem if you are using a 32-bit system.  Java requires a single continuous block of memory to start Java. If you start Java with close to the maximum amount of memory, whether you get that memory as a single block depends on what you have already running on that server.

Solutions include

- start Java as a service on start up.
- use a 64-bit version of the OS and Java.
- use less memory in the JVM, even 100 Mb could make a difference.
- increase the amount of main memory in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

In starting up the Tomcat server, you can change the program parameters when running Java. You can add to the VM arguments -Xmx###m to a smaller number that may work on your machine. Also, you may want to see if you're running other memory intensive Java apps.